# sinon testing ember.js .then method

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js, coffeescript, sinon

The following 2 functions are in coffeescript, ember.js functions

```
fetchPage: (params) ->
    @store.find 'device', params

getMore: (params) ->

      nextPage = @get('page') + 1
      params.page = nextPage || 1 #when page is null, nextpage still 1
      @fetchPage(params).then (devices) =>
         @send 'gotMore', devices, nextPage
```

How to test the last 2 lines:

```
@fetchPage(params).then (devices) =>
   @send 'gotMore', devices, nextPage
```

I tried the following but did not work

```
test 'actions: getMore - not at last page & page exists', ->
  Em.run =>
    @params = @store.createRecord('device', {id: 1, page: 6})
  # params = {page: 99}
  metaDataStub = sinon.stub(@store, 'metadataFor')
  deviceMetaData = {total_pages: 8}
  metaDataStub.withArgs('device').returns(deviceMetaData)

  fetchPageStub = sinon.stub(@controller, 'fetchPage')
  @controller.set 'page', 6

  @controller.send 'getMore', @params
  equal params.page,7, 'params.page set to next page'
  ok fetchPageStub.calledWithExactly(@params), 'fetchPage called'
  metaDataStub.restore()

test 'actions: getMore - not at last page & page not existed', ->
  params = {page: 99}
  metaDataStub = sinon.stub(@store, 'metadataFor')
  deviceMetaData = {total_pages: 8}
  metaDataStub.withArgs('device').returns(deviceMetaData)
  @controller.set 'page', null

  @controller.send 'getMore', params
  equal params.page,1, 'params.page set to 1 when next page not exist'
  metaDataStub.restore()
```

It throws an error of: "`Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`" where the code is marked with ********
Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is actually return a promise, like:

```
promise = Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve()
  reject()
})
```

if you want to test what is inside the 'then', then return some data in the 'resolve' function of the promise.

then, you could test that it gets called by doing something like:

```
mock = sinon.mock(controller);
mock.expects('fetchPage').once.returns(promise); // the promise defined earlier
```

and you could use the same lines to test that the other method(gotMore), gets called with the right arguments:

```
mock.expects('gotMore').once.withArgs(whateverYouReturnInReolve, whateverPageNumberIs)
```